# Range of $f(x,y)=\frac{4x^2+(y+2)^2}{x^2+y^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am trying to find the range of this function:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{4x^2+(y+2)^2}{x^2+y^2+1}$$

So I think that means I have to find minima and maxima. Using partial derivatives gets messy, so I was wondering if I could do some change of variables to make it easier computationally. But no change of coordinates that I can think of have really simplified it much. If I set $2w=y+2$, then I get a problem below. Am I thinking of the right strategy, or is there something better I could do?

Comment: Note that $f(x,y)\ge0$

Comment: I believe it would be useful to expand the square on top & rearrange the values to get $f(x,y) = 4 + \frac{4y-3y^2}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}$.

Comment: Thanks, this was a really fruitful approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: $$f(x,y) =\frac{4x^2+4y^2+4+(y+2)^2-4y^2-4}{x^2+y^2+1}$$

$$=4+\frac{-3y^2+4y}{x^2+y^2+1}$$

$$\leq 4+\frac{-3y^2+4y}{y^2+1}$$ if $-3y^2+4y\geq 0$ (else it is reversed),

$$= 1+\frac{4y+3}{y^2+1} =:g(y)$$

So you have to find a maximum value of $g$ on $[0,{4\over 3}]$.

Comment: If you expand the numerator, you get $4x^2 + y^2 + 4y + 4 = (4x^2 + 4y^2 + 4) - 3y^2 + 4y$. This gives the result that I stated in my question comment. You have an extra term of $3$ in the numerator.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! for reference minima and maxima are $0$ and $5$.

Answer (score 2):

See fig. below.

$5$ is the maximum. More precisely :

$$f(x,y):=\dfrac{4x^2+(y-2)^2}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}\leq 5 \tag{1}$$

with case of equality iff

$$(x,y)=(0,1/2)\tag{2}$$

Here is why : we form the "gap" between the LHS and RHS of (1) :

$$5-\dfrac{4x^2+(y-2)^2}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}=\dfrac{x^2+(2y - 1)^2}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}$$

This gap is always >0 with the exceptional case given by (2).

Besides, $0$ is clearly the minimum, realized for $(x,y)=(0,2)$.

Now the last question : is the range of values of function $f$ the whole interval $[0,5]$ ? Answer : yes by continuity.

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Surface $z=f(x,y)$ with its unique minimum and maximum.*

Answer (score 2):

For
$$f(x,y)=\frac{4x^2+(y+2)^2}{x^2+y^2+1}$$
partial derivatives are not so terrifying:
\begin{align}
D_1f(x,y)&=\frac{8x(x^2+y^2+1)-2x(4x^2+(y+2)^2)}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}\\[4px]
&=\frac{2xy(3y-4)}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}
\\[8px]
D_2f(x,y)&=\frac{2(y+2)(x^2+y^2+1)-2y(4x^2+(y+2)^2)}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}\\[4px]
&=\frac{2(-3x^2y+2x^2-2y^2-3y+2)}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}
\end{align}
The first derivative vanishes for $x=0$, $y=0$ or $y=4/3$.

We have (the denominator is irrelevant as it doesn't vanish)
\begin{align}
D_2f(0,y)&=\frac{-2(2y^2+3y-2)}{\dots} \\[4px]
D_2f(x,0)&=\frac{4(x^2+1)}{\dots} \\[4px]
D_2f(x,4/3)&=\frac{-4(x^2+19/3)}{\dots}
\end{align}
Thus we only get critical points for $x=0$ and $2y^2+3y-2=0$, that is, $y=-2$ or $y=1/2$.

Since $f(0,-2)=0$ and $f(0,1/2)=5$, the minimum is $0$ and the maximum is $5$.

Well, how do we know that $0$ is the minimum? Because obviously the function only takes on nonnegative values. Why $(0,5)$ is a point of maximum and not a saddle point? Because $f(x,y)$ is bounded:
$$
f(x,y)\le\frac{4x^2+4(y+2)^2}{x^2+y^2+1}=4+\frac{16y+12}{x^2+y^2+1}\le16+\frac{16y}{x^2+y^2+1}
$$
Now note that $|y|\le x^2+y^2+1$, because $|y|^2-|y|+1\ge0$. Thus
$$
|f(x,y)|\le 32
$$
Hence the function *must* have an absolute maximum which has to be at a critical point. Checking with the Hessian would be indeed a nuisance.

Comment: Ah thanks for this alternate approach. That was a neat way of skipping the computation of the hessian.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$f(x,y)\le 5$$  if
$$4x^2+(y+2)^2\le 5x^2+5y^2+5$$ if
$$0\le x^2+(2y-1)^2$$ and clearly we get $$f(x,y)\geq 0$$

Comment: Although the answers are correct, I do not understand the motivation between those inequalities. I can't see how you obtained the triple 5's.